# In Xamarin, How Do I Remove the Native iOS View Controller to Re-Expose the PCL Undearneath

Tags: xamarin, dependency-injection, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using dependency injection to fireup Wikitude from my PCL on iOS Native Xamarin. This works fine. I added a button on Wikitude to exit and go back to the PCL - this works fine up the the point where I need to Delete or Remove the ViewController or Storyboard I originally created. Not sure how to do it..

To start Wikitude we do:

```
    public void LaunchWikitude()
    {
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard_iPhone", null);
    var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StoryBoardViewController") as UIViewController;

    //var window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    window.RootViewController = controller;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```

And to stop Wikitude and go back to the PCL (where I'm stuck):

```
    public override void InvokedURL(WTArchitectView architectView, NSUrl url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("architect view invoked url: " + url);
        //architectView.Stop();

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;


    }
```

Comment: when you assign RootViewController you need to keep a ref to it's previous value so you can restore it when you're done

Comment: got it. I was think that. Thank you. I'll give it a try.